# Haystack more_like_this returns all

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I am using Django, haystack, solr, to do searching.  Ive am able to search and now I would like to find similar items using more_like_this. When I try to use the more_like_this functionality I get back all of the objects that are of that model type instead of just the ones that closely match it. Here is some code to show you how I am using it:

```
def resource_view(request, slug):
    resource = Resource.objects.get(slug=slug)
    versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(resource)
    related = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(resource)
    add_comment_form = AddCommentForm()
    return render_to_response('resources/resource.html',
                              {'resource': resource,
                               'versions': versions,
                               'related': related,
                               'add_comment_form': add_comment_form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Apparently I need to enable mlt in the solrconfig.xml file.  Anyone know how to do this, or an article/tutorial that is helpful?

Comment: It looks to me like you're using it correctly, but do you have it enabled in `solrconfig.xml`?

Comment: youre right I dont have it enabled in solrconfig.xml,  can you point me to a good tutorial or article on how to do that?

Comment: you can add configuration in below answer in your solrconfig.xml then restart solar

Answer (score 4):

stale question, but here's the answer anyway:

As John already pointed out, you need to add the more like this handler (MLT) to your solr config. This should do, put it somewhere in your solrconfig.xml, and reload SOLR (Tomcat):

```
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
  <str name="mlt.mindf">1</str>
  <str name="mlt.minwl">3</str>
  <str name="mlt.maxwl">15</str>
  <str name="mlt.maxqt">20</str>
  <str name="mlt.match.include">false</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm having a similar problem, i've correctly added this configuration to solrconfig.xml but te more_like_this method is returnin empty results. Any ideas what may be happening?