# haystack + elasticsearch more_like_this: all results have a score of 1.0

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

The docs mention a [special handler that needs to be configured](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html?highlight=elasticsearch#more-like-this) to get the feature to work with Solr. Nothing for Elasticsearch, though.
Search works well, returning hits with meaningful scores. `more_like_this`, however, works the same way as [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064753) (except I use the Elasticsearch backend, not Solr)

What need I do?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @matthewwilkes Nope, I used Solr, and later it was taken out of my hands. Should the question be closed if unanswered?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid! I'm just trying to sort out my own MLT/elasticsearch woes and am struggling to find mistakes.